# Highcharts won't slant data on a bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have been trying to get text to slant using the bat chart of highcharts without results.

I have 14 options point for data on the yAxis and I have put in rotation values but the text does not rotate. From the examples that I see, always use the xAxis as an example. I'm pretty much locked into this specific type of chart.

Full code is posted here. Snippet of the code will follow. fiddle posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/gTQ75/1/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Testing Phase'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Phase'],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {

                    categories: ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6', 'Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9', 'Option10', 'Option11', 'Option12', 'Option13', 'Option14'],
        labels: {
            rotation: 270,
        y:40  
        },
```

The overall goal would be to use this chart and have the text slanted at a 45 degree angle. I also think that having the text flow vertically would be acceptable as well.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you have `yAxis.labels` property in there twice. It is using the second one which just states to set it to justify. Combine these two into one or remove the second one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll green this as soon as it lets me. Also, for some reason it's not starting at 0, it's sort of starting at .5 between otpion1 and option 2. What will make it line up on the lines?